# Why do we need this type definition? 'RegExpExecArray | null' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: javascript, regex

```
const test = (
    a: string,
    b: string,
  ): [string, string] => {
    if (a.match(/^\d+$/)) {
      return [a, b];
    }
    const [_, firstA, secondB]: any = /(\d*)\-*(([\s\S]*))/.exec(a);
    return [firstA, secondB];
  };
```

why do we need this type definition here?const [_, firstA, secondB]: **any** = /(\d*)-*(([\s\S]*))/.exec(a);?

If i don't specify the type then i get an error : " Type 'RegExpExecArray | null' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)
"

Answer (score 0):

The following

```
/(\d*)\-*(([\s\S]*))/.exec(a)
```

Can return null, which will cause an error with the destructuring assignment, consider the following:

```
const [a, b] = null; // Uncaught TypeError: null has no properties
```

Your `: any` will hide this fact.

One way to get around this is to append  `?? ['', '', '']` to the end of the line, which will cause  `[_, firstA, secondB]` to all be assigned to empty strings, if there isn't a match.

Then you can in theory also get rid of the return type for the function, as this will be inferred to `string[]`:

```
  const test = (
    a: string,
    b: string,
  ) => {
    if (a.match(/^\d+$/)) {
      return [a, b];
    }
    const [_, firstA, secondB] = /(\d*)\-*(([\s\S]*))/.exec(a) ?? ['', '', ''];
    return [firstA, secondB];
  };
```

You can also assign the output of `.exec` to an intermediate variable and return something different it's `null`:

```
  const test = (
    a: string,
    b: string,
  ) => {
    if (a.match(/^\d+$/)) {
      return [a, b];
    }
    const fields = /(\d*)\-*(([\s\S]*))/.exec(a);
    if (!fields) {
      return ['', '']; // return something relevant here
    }
    const [_, firstA, secondB] = fields;
    return [firstA, secondB];
  };
```